# Undo/Redo operation is not working on WPF Richtext box with Syntax highlighting

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, undo-redo

I am using RichTextBox in one of my WPF Application, users types Text\script in this rich text box, based on the tokens entered by user i apply color, font property to the entered text in the code behind(Syntax highlighting).

I need to perform Undo\Redo Operations, but what i found is the default undo operation works well if i am not changing the color\font properties, but if i change them in my code , it doesnt work.

I read many postings here which are mainly discussing about richtext box undo operations in C#, most of them suggested to use logic using stack and storing text and poping the text for undo\redo. But the problem i have in WPF is i need to know the TextPointers for inserting the text and also i need to know the operations like delete, add and copy paste text operations for my undo\redo operations.

Is there a way where i can perform these operations although property changes are done to text.

Comment: good question, however, you should edit it to improve readability.